# Sympy diff() gives wrong result whenever i set symbol to real

Tags: python, sympy

I don't understand why when I set the symbol to real `diff()` seem to consider it a constant:

```
>>> t = sympify("x^2")
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> diff(t,x)
2*x
>>> x1=Symbol('x',real=True)
>>> diff(t,x1)
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the variable `x` in `t` and the variable `x1` are *not* considered the same, due to the "real" attribute of `x1`. Hence, in the differentiation the `x1` variable is treated as a constant, yielding `0`.

To fix this if you intend on working with real variables, you can define your expression with a real variable `x`.

```
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> t = sympify('x^2', locals={'x': x})
>>> diff(t, x)
2*x
```

Instead of passing an explicit dict with the `locals` keyword argument, you could also just call [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) with `locals=locals()` to pull in all the entire local symbol table as a dict, which may be useful if you have many Symbol variables.

Comment: You can also write `locals=locals()` in sympify to pull in all the local variables, including `x`.

Comment: @asmeurer That's worth noting, could make things easier. Mind if I add it to my answer?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. No need to ask to revise your own answer.